# How to send a message to an Agent in Main Container via http in Jade?

Tags: java, javaagents, agents-jade

I want to connect to an agent created in Main Container which runs on a computer. Assume the Main COntainer ID is Main-Container@192.118.2.3 How can i connect to a agent inside that container and pass data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a ContainerController (whether for a main container or an agent container doesn't matter) that's part of the agent platform you're concerned with.

An easy way to get one would be just to create a new agent container and connect it to the platform.

```
import jade.core.Runtime;
import jade.core.Profile;
import jade.core.ProfileImpl;

...

Runtime myRuntime = Runtime.instance();

// prepare the settings for the platform that we're going to connect to
Profile myProfile = new ProfileImpl();
myProfile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_HOST, "myhost");
myProfile.setParameter(Profile.MAIN_PORT, "1099");

// create the agent container
ContainerController myContainer = myRuntime.createAgentContainer(myProfile);
```

then, you can use the `getAgent()` method of the ContainerController to get an AgentController.

```
AgentController myAgentController = myContainer.getAgent("agent-local-name");
```

finally, if you would like to pass data to the Agent, you can do so using O2A (Object 2 Agent) messages. This basically allows you to pass any object to the agent through an agent controller.

```
Object myObject = "Real-Object-Would-Go-Here";
myAgentController.putO2AObject(myObject, false);
```

within the agent (preferably within a behaviour), you can listen for that object like this:

```
// start accepting O2A communications
setEnabledO2ACommunication(true, 0);
// start monitoring them
addBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour(this) {
    @Override
    public void action() {
        // get an object from the O2A mailbox
        Object myObject = myAgent.getO2AObject();

        // if we actually got one
        if(myObject != null) {
            // do something with it
        } else {
            block();
        }
    }
});
```

Sources: JADE documentation

- [ContainerController](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/wrapper/ContainerController.html)
- [AgentController](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/wrapper/AgentController.html)
- [Agent](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/core/Agent.html)